# Proof of power rule of limit

Tags: limits

I would like someone to verify whether or not my proof of the statement bellow is correct. Thank you.
$$\lim_{x \to f(a)} f(x)^5 $$ equals $$\ (lim_{x \to f(a)} f(x))^5 $$ So I assumed $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a) $$ and $$\lim_{x \to f(a)} g(x) = g(f(a)) $$ Further assumptions I took are $$\ g(f(x))=f(x)^5 $$ The proof goes as follows $$\lim_{x \to f(a)} f(x)^5=\lim_{x \to f(a)} g(f(x))=g(f(a))=g(\lim_{x \to a} f(x))=(\lim_{x \to a} f(x))^5 $$

Answer (score 1):

$lim_{x \to a} g(f(x))= g(lim_{x \to a} f(x))$ if g(x) is continuous in the neighborhood of f(a). In this case since the function is $x^5$ which is continuous in x $\in R$, so your usage here is correct